# How can I access a specific value from a JSON response in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm trying to make a `POST` on an API so I can get a bearer token.

Example:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api");

var request = new RestRequest();

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("client_id", "X");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
request.AddParameter("client_secret", "X");

var response = client.Post(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

The response is this JSON:

```
{ 
  "access_token": "aisodjaisjd4123",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599
}
```

How can I store that `aisodjaisjd4123` into a variable?

Comment: What research have you done on the subject of JSON parsing? What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serialise this json to a class object. And then access_token member will have token value.

You can use [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialise the string to object. You can search it in Nuget Package manager.

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class Root
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
     }
```

And please ignore the indentation, I have typed from phone.